# Display a GTK 3.0 Image failed Python

Tags: python, image, gtk, spyder

I am developing with Spyder IDE a program that have a Splash Screen. I used this solution:

```
class Splash():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        self.window.set_title("Launching Astrogator initalized!")
        self.window.set_decorated(False)
        self.window.set_resizable(False)
        self.window.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.window.set_icon_from_file("artwork/icon/icon.svg")

# A solution before    
#        self.image = Gtk.Image()
#        self.image.set_from_file('artwork/splash/splash_small.png')
#        self.image.show()
#        self.window.add(self.image)
        box = Gtk.VBox()
        image_area = Gtk.Box()
        box.add(image_area)
        image = Gtk.Image()
        image.set_from_file('./artwork/splash/splash_small.png')
        image_area.add(image)
        image_area.show_all()
        self.window.add(box)

        self.window.show_all()

    def destroy(self):
        self.destroy = Gtk.Window.destroy(self)
        self.destroy

if __name__ == "__main__":
    splashScreen = Splash()
    while Gtk.events_pending():
        Gtk.main_iteration()
    sleep(3)
    astrogatorApp = App() # Main GUI. No displayed code
    splashScreen.window.destroy()

    Gtk.main()
```

When I run it on Spyder first there is no problem. But at second the splash image is not displayed and the window is transparent.

When I run it from Terminal the image is at first run also not there ...

How it could work that the image is every time displayed?

Sincerely,
Jakob Krieger

Comment: Any particular reason why you're rolling your own mainloop instead of using `Gtk.main()`?

Comment: No, but deleting this solves the problem not ...

Comment: And what´s your opinion to do this?

Comment: Using `gtk.main()` has solved the problem for me. If it doesn't for you, then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Yes, Gtk.main() at the end of Splash.__init__() solves the problem, but only on the half. The second GUI won´t be started instantly, only when the Splash Screen is closed ...

Comment: But isn't that the point? You have three seconds of the splash screen, and then the splash screen closes and the main window opens?